# How do I convert a string with a first name and last name to an object w/ properties of {firstName: "string first name", lastName: "string last name}?

Tags: javascript, string

```js
function convertNameToObject(string) {

    let obj = {};
    obj.firstName = ;
    obj.lastName = ;
    return obj;

}
console.log(convertNameToObject("Harry Potter"));
```

Comment: Use `String.prototype.split` function and split the argument by space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split on the space character.

```js
function convertNameToObject(string) {
    const [firstName, lastName] = string.split(" ");
    return { firstName, lastName };
}
console.log(convertNameToObject("Harry Potter"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Little improved version that originally was provided by @Samathingamajig.

In the body of function there is IIFE expression.

```js
function convertNameToObject(string) {
    return (([firstName, lastName]) => ({firstName, lastName}))(string.split(" "))

}
console.log(convertNameToObject("Harry Potter"));
```